# Still Trying to Bind a Nested Property Model to a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding, datagrid

I wrote a minimal version of my problem, it only contains a DataGrid with 3 columns.

Requirements:

(a) The two ComboBox-filled columns must be implemented with identical definitions and processing. They must be essentially copy&paste of each other.

(b) I cannot use the simple approach, based on `List<string>`. I need a more featureful custom object.

Without further ado, there you go...

http://patriot.net/~ramon/app-question/

Question: Why doesn't my Right Column bind? What is it missing?

TIA,

-Travis

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You need to click on the link above. This is the most elaborated question I have ever posted. In essence the question is: How can I make that code work?

Comment: Hi Travis, in the future please try to include all the relevant code in your question itself so users don't have to click on external links (that could potentially go dead in the future) to view the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Rachel: This is a unique circumstance (at least for me). First time that I have to create a web page in order to *clearly* illustrate the problem and question. I tried your suggestion already in the original posts but it was too hard to follow several files, plus images. Got zero replies. This is about my 10th. attempt and it was solved in a matter of minutes! I finally made the extra effort to prepare my case (as a good lawyer would :-).

Comment: I promise I will leave those files in that web server for a long time. The solution would be that StackOverflow allowed attachments (like Adobe or even Usenet) BUT it creates the possibility of malware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your right column is wrong. You're using `SelectedValue` where it should be `SelectedItem`, and you need to bind directly to the item instead of it's value:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header=" Right Column ">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox
                ItemsSource="{Binding Caliber, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Mode=OneWay}"
                DisplayMemberPath="Thickness"
                SelectedItem="{Binding Selection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

                <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Enabled}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And please, remove all the unneeded code, and use `foreach` instead of `for` loops and use the `var` keyword where appropiate, and use `object initializer`s where appropiate.